# Intercepting web requests in .NET to add proxy information

Tags: .net, bing-maps, infragistics

I'm using a .NET library (Infragistics XamGeographicMap) that is making http requests to the Bing maps tile server. The library is closed source so I can't access the internals.

The library and configuration is all working and when it runs on a machine with a direct internet connection, the map displays just fine. However, from within a corporate proxy, none of the tiles load and the map is displayed as a blank screen.

I cannot find any property in the Infragistics.Controls.Maps.BingMapsTileSource or Infragistics.Controls.Maps.BingMapsMapImagery objects that would allow me to specify details for the Proxy server, so I need some way, from within the application, to intercept the web requests and redirect them through the proxy.

I *can* change the URL that the Infragistics component is using for Bing maps, so one approach I'm considering changing the URL from

```
http://ecn.{subdomain}.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r{quadkey}.jpeg?g=5256&mkt={culture}&shading=hill
```

to

```
prox://ecn.{subdomain}.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r{quadkey}.jpeg?g=5256&mkt={culture}&shading=hill
```

And then registering a new prefix using

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("prox", new ProxWebRequestCreate());
```

To intercept the WebRequests, make the real request through the proxy server and then return that to the server.

Is this a viable approach and if so, how might I implement the ProxyWebRequestCreate object? Is there a simpler solution that I've not considered?

Comment: I'd try asking to Infragistics first. If you did it, what did they answer you?

Comment: I haven't asked them, I don't have a support package, so I can only access the forums. Even for that I need to sign up. As a workaround I've changed the application wide proxy settings and that seems to work okay.